# Can we start a comparatve sentense with "compared to"

Tags: grammaticality

Compared to small animal, larger animal had more fat with higher body weight.

Can we start a comparatve sentense with "compared to"

Comment: This is your sixth question here, and in five of them the **same word** has been misspelled, and the misspelling pointed out. Are you able to understand the comments? Do you have an English dictionary to consult?

Comment: Yes, you can begin with this clause. However, there is another very important element missing. Do you know what every singular, countable noun requires?

Comment: Many thanks  P. E. Dant. May I request you to explain a bit about another very important missing element?

Comment: Do you understand that you have misspelled the same word in five questions? Do you know what that word is? If you can read and understand this comment, please tell us. Knowing what you can understand will make easier to provide you with useful advice and answers.

Answer (score 1):

"Compared to" is used correctly here.

But there are other problems with this sentence. For example, could be "Compared to *the* small animal, *the* larger animal had more fat *and a* higher body weight."

Comment: A determiner is needed, but not necessarily the definitive article. *Compared to some small animal, this larger animal…* would be equally grammatical, though of course the meaning would change.